# How can I change the text on a ListView that is holding an Object of type AccountInfo?

Tags: java, listview, netbeans, javafx

I am making a password manager using JavaFX and I am holding all the relevant info from the user's account in a listview and they can select the item in the list to display it on a form to the right. At this point the listview is just displaying text relevant to the object that is is holding. I would like to display the name of the site that the account info is for. I have a getSiteName() method on the AccountInfo class, but I don't know how to set the text in the list view. Looking for some guidance here! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a csutom CellFactory and override how it renders item's text by overrideing `updateItem` method:

```
lv.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<AccountInfo>, ListCell<AccountInfo>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<AccountInfo> call(ListView<AccountInfo> param) {
         ListCell<AccountInfo> cell = new ListCell<AccountInfo>() {
             @Override
            protected void updateItem(AccountInfo item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if(item != null) {
                    setText(item.getSiteName());
                } else {
                    setText(null);
                }
            }
         };
        return cell;
    }
});
```

Comment: Glad to be helpful.